# Ошибка The view file does not exist: G:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\yii2lesson\views\album\index.php

Tags: yii2

Делала так, как на  скриншоте: http://prntscr.com/b11ulo
Набираю в браузере строку http://yii2lesson/index.php?r=album%2Findex ,-
вылезает следующая ошибка: http://prntscr.com/b11vb5

Comment: Вы точно все создали ?

Comment: не надо заполнять view path

Answer (score 0):

не надо заполнять поле `view path`

Answer (score 0):

В полях **Model class**, **Search model Class** и **Controller Class** указываются полные имена классов, включая пространства имен. Например **app\models\Album**.

В поле **View Path** указывается путь к каталогу для создания представлений. Например **G:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\yii2lesson\views\album**. 
Для удобства, в **Yii 2** можно использовать [**псевдонимы (алиасы)**](http://nix-tips.ru/yii2-api-guides/guide-ru-concept-aliases.html) и указать путь так: **@app/views/album**.

В вашем случае можно вообще поле **View Path** оставить пустым, **Gii** сам подставит нужный путь.

Плюс ко всему, в **Gii** есть удобные всплывающие подсказки с примерами заполнения:
[image: Yii 2 Gii popup hint]